# Как из строчки выделить числа двухзначные и больше

Tags: python

```
lst = []
lst2 = []
with open('some.txt') as a:
    for i in a.readline():
        try:
            int(i)
            lst.append(i)
        except:
            lst2.append(i)
print(lst)
print(lst2)
```

В файле находится строчка наподобие:
    o4b8y9q16l6r1n1t20o13p2o18h14i4j2u20l8c14e5j16l11
Как выделить двухзначные числа и добавить их в словарь?

Comment: а трёхзначные и более могут быть?

Comment: Могут,но у меня задача научиться, а не скопировать решение, так что я сделаю их по аналогии)

Comment: для пары чисел и для неопределённого ряда чисел - немного разные задачи) по аналогии не сделать

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
result = re.findall(r'(\d{2,})', 'o4b8y9q16l6r1n1t20o13p2o18h14i4j2u20l8c14e5j16l11')
print(result)
```

2 вариант(только 2 символа):

```
a = 'o4b8y9q16l6r1n1t20o13p2o18h14i4j2u20l8c14e5j16l11'
[x+z for x, z in zip(a, a[1:]) if x.isdigit() and z.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string_ = 'o4b8y9q16l6r1n1t20o13p2o18h14i4j2u20l8c14e5j16l11' # Запишите содержимое txt файла в переменную
temp = '' # Временное хранилище для чисел
numbers = [] # Список с подходящими числами
for i in string_:
    global temp, numbers
    if i.isdigit():
        temp += i
        if len(temp) == 2:
            numbers.append(int(temp))
            temp = ''
    else:
        temp = ''

print(numbers) # [16, 20, 13, 18, 14, 20, 14, 16, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In:
import re
file = 'blablabla1blablabla23lbabla4ff03q2'
x = re.findall('(\d+)', file)
for i in x:
    if len(i) < 2:
        x.remove(i)
Out:
['23', '03']
```

Конечно наверное надо предусмотреть возможность нахождения чисел типа `'00004'` . Но это вы сами сможете сделать надеюсь.